# Reading XLS from another website

Tags: php, excel

I´m trying to read this XLS file so I can output it using an excel reader library

```
 http://www.bcv.org.ve/excel/1_2_1.xls
```

But i get an error of 'not readable'

I tried:

```
readfile()
get_contents()
```

and with those I get a bunch of weird symbols.

and of course, the main function used by the reader:

```
$data->read('http://www.bcv.org.ve/excel/1_2_1.xls');
```

but i get the error not readable

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You'll have great difficulty loading a remote Excel workbook into any Excel Reader library because the reader almost certainly uses the filesystem functions like fseek() which aren't all supported for remote file streams. Download the file to your server, and then load it from your local filesystem.

Comment: Yes mark I figured that out :( Im having trouble downloading the file to my server, through php, could you give me a sample code or tell me the appropiate functions to use? curl , readfile, get contents are all corrupting the file

Comment: Are you sure the file is being corrupted? Any of those methods should work. Will the downloaded file open in MS Excel itself?